# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).each is not a function after updating wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, divi

I'm using the wordpress theme 'Divi'. After updating, some custom jQuery I added into the footer template that has worked for the last several years has broken and I can't figure out how to get it working again.

This is what is in my footer template:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
    jQuery('[id=beer_right]').each(function(){  
        var text = (jQuery(this).text());  
        console.log(text);
        var substring = text.substring(1,3);
        var substring100 = text.substring(1,4);
            if(substring100 == "100"){
            jQuery(this).addClass('full')
        }else if (substring >= 60 && substring <= 99){
                jQuery(this).addClass('full')
        }else if(substring >= 30 && substring <= 59){
            jQuery(this).addClass('half')
        }else{
            jQuery(this).addClass('empty')
        }
    });
    jQuery("[id=bottle_right]").each(function(){  
        var text2 = (jQuery(this).text());  
        var substring2 = text2.substring(2,4);
        //console.log(substring2);
            if(substring2 == "17" || substring2 == "16" || substring2 == "15" || substring2 == "14" || substring2 == "13" || substring2 == "12" || substring2 == "11" || substring2 == "10" || substring2 == "9%"){
                jQuery(this).addClass('strong')
        }else if(substring2 == "8%" || substring2 == "7%" || substring2 == "6%"){
            jQuery(this).addClass('average')
        }else{
            jQuery(this).addClass('light')
        }
    })
     if (jQuery('.app-link').length){
            if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
            var applink = jQuery('.app-link');
            applink.attr("href", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AuphanSoftware.OftenDining");
            }
            if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") > -1){
            var applink = jQuery('.app-link');
            applink.attr("href", "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/often-dining/id608504639?mt=8")
             }
     }

})(jQuery); 
</script>




<script>
(function($){
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 585) {
        jQuery('.et_pb_tabs_controls > li').click(function() {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: jQuery(".et_pb_all_tabs").offset().top
                }, 2000);
        });
        }
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

The error I'm getting in the console for each of these is:

```
(index):5831 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).each is not a function

(index):5877 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).width is not a function
```

Website is: https://sdtaproom.com/beer

Comment: You have IIFE wrappers as `(function($){ ... })(jQuery)`. Because of this, you should be using `$` inside those functions, not `jQuery`, as in `(function($){ ... $() ... })(jQuery)`.

Comment: @Ouroborus if I do the above then I get this error in the console instead:
$(...).each is not a function

Comment: Just so you know, you should still make that change for the reason I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove jquery from your wp?
If not, you don't need to make this call > () before the function

The function is correct, and works in the console, the error is due to the loading lifecycle of the jquery being loaded.

sorry about my English

Comment: I didn't do anything myself to remove jquery from wp. Are you referring to adding the jquery library before my script tags? If so, I have tried removing the jquery library and I still receive the same error in the console.

But the function I have does work within the console itself. So there is something going on with the JQuery library I believe. I'm just not sure what exactly it is and what to do about it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using the plugin 'autoptimize' which was aggregating the JS. I turned this off and it's working now